# How to automatically add a Apache HTTP vHost

Tags: apache, http

I’m trying to add a vHost automatically to Apache, the request initially comes from a PHP file with hostname, port ip etc. Everything you need to add a vHost but I can’t find anything in the documentations of adding vHosts mayby someone can help me oud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, create a vhost file with php and save it in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`forder than create reload apache2, that works.